# Show message on button click and on keyboard "enter"

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am working on a script and made it to function; however, I can't figure out how to make the @giobianchi's code work when the user hits "enter" on the keyboard. I assume we'd need to add another event listener with "keypress" or similar. I'd need the messages to show up on either enter or click.

The code is essentially [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695758/trying-to-add-a-submit-button-and-then-it-would-display-the-msg-i-am-very-ne). Thanks to the helpers there! I'm just struggling to find a solution that would work with this setup. Unless there's a better way to achieve the same thing?

Would greatly appreciate some guidance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="zipCode" placeholder="Enter ZIP code" />
        <button id="checkButton">Check</button>
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById("checkButton");
            
            function checkIfAvailable(zip) {
                let zones = ["60004", "60005", "60006"]
                return (zones.indexOf(zip) >= 0);
            }
            
            button.addEventListener("click", function validateZip() {
                let zip = document.getElementById("zipCode").value;
                let msg = "";
                if (checkIfAvailable(zip)) {
                    msg = "Service is available your area!";
                } else {
                    msg = "Sorry, we do not service your area yet.";
                }
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;
            });

                     
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding a second event listener with "keyup" to no avail.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="zipCode" placeholder="Enter ZIP code" />
        <button id="checkButton">Check</button>
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById("checkButton");
            
            function checkIfAvailable(zip) {
                let zones = ["60004", "60005", "60006"]
                return (zones.indexOf(zip) >= 0);
            }
            
            button.addEventListener("click", function validateZip() {
                let zip = document.getElementById("zipCode").value;
                let msg = "";
                if (checkIfAvailable(zip)) {
                    msg = "Service is available your area!";
                } else {
                    msg = "Sorry, we do not service your area yet.";
                }
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;
            });
                button.addEventListener("keyup", function validateZip() {
                    let zip = document.getElementById("zipCode").value;
                    let msg = "";
                    if (checkIfAvailable(zip)) {
                    msg = "Service is available your area!";
                } else {
                    msg = "Sorry, we do not service your area yet.";
                }
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;
            });
  
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think, try to wrap your <input/> and <button/> element with a <form> tag

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but now after hitting enter, the whole page reloads, and "/?" appears after the URL. What could be causing this?

Comment: to prevent page reloading, I think, you need to call `preventDefault()` inside your `validateZip(e)` function. Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056105/10811003 for more deets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("checkButton");
      var input = document.getElementById("zipCode");
      
      function checkIfAvailable(zip) {
        let zones = ["60004", "60005", "60006"];
        return zones.includes(zip);
      }
      
      function validateZip() {
        let zip = input.value;
        let msg = "";
        if (checkIfAvailable(zip)) {
          msg = "Service is available in your area!";
        } else {
          msg = "Sorry, we do not service your area yet.";
        }
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;
      }
      
      button.addEventListener("click", validateZip);
      input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
          validateZip();
        }
      });
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much! It subtly rewrites my original approach; I would not have figured this out on my own. Grateful for your help, Asmita.